# storing issue: all goes well but the script stores not at the intended place

Tags: perl, firefox, mechanize, www-mechanize, storage

Well to me Perl sometimes looks abit Abracadabra 
so many thanks for the patience with me...

**update;** joe asked me to post the full script that isnt workin: here we have the code that i have tried out after mobs answer (see below)

getting **serious errors** all the way long:

```
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
syntax error at test_8.pl line 25, near ")
 binmode"
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 25.
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 26.
Execution of test_8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> su -
```

here the script i run currently...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open my $urls, '<', 'urls.txt' or die $!;

while (<$urls>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /^http/i;
  print "$_\n";
  $mech->get($_);
  my $png = $mech->content_as_png;
  my $name = $_;
  $name =~ s#^http://##i;
  $name =~ s#/##g;
  $name =~ s/\s+\z//;
  $name =~ s/\A\s+//;
  $name =~ s/^www\.//;
  $name .= ".png";
 open(my $out, '>', "/images/$name")
 binmode $out;
  print $out $png;
  close $out;
  sleep 5;
}
```

and here are **five sample urls...**

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
```

end of update; and here the **original initial-thread continues...**

i need to have some thumbnails from websites but i tried to use wget - but that does not work for me, since i need 
some rendering functions what is needet: i have a list of 2,500 URLs, one on each line, saved in a file. Then i  want a script - see it below - to open the file, read a line, then retrieve the website and save  the image as a small thumbnail. 
well since i have a bunch of web-sites (2500) i have to make up my mind about the naming of the results.

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
http://www.phtg.ch
http://www.phsg.ch
http://www.phsh.ch
http://www.phr.ch
http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
```

So far so good, well i think i try something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open my $urls, '<', 'urls.txt' or die $!;

while (<$urls>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /^http/i;
  print "$_\n";
  $mech->get($_);
  my $png = $mech->content_as_png;
  my $name = $_;
  $name =~ s#^http://##i;
  $name =~ s#/##g;
  $name =~ s/\s+\z//;
  $name =~ s/\A\s+//;
  $name =~ s/^www\.//;
  $name .= ".png";
  open my $out, ">", $ "images" or die $!;
  binmode $out;
  print $out $png;
  close $out;
  sleep 5;
}
```

running a little script and collecting / getting results... i gather images as thumbnails.
so far so good.

**Note:** all is nice and runs well so far   untill - yes untill i 
tried to create a special option: i wanted to force the script to do some storing of the results in a folder

Well, what do you think about the idea of storing the results in a folder called images or so!?) is this doable? it would help alot since i get stored the results in a folder. 
And the many results do not mess the machine...

i run into some issues.  tried to do it - to store it in a directory thusly:

`open(my $out, '>', "path/$name") or die $!;` i did it like so..

note - **the directory called images** is in the very same folder...

i get the results

```
  perl test_8.pl

Global symbol "$images" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 23.
Execution of test_8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> 
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at test_8.pl line 23, near "$/images"
        (Missing operator before images?)
syntax error at test_8.pl line 23, near "$/images "
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 24.
Execution of test_8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at test_8.pl line 23, near "$/images"
        (Missing operator before images?)
syntax error at test_8.pl line 23, near "$/images "
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 24.
Execution of test_8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> 
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at test_8.pl line 23, near "$ "images"
        (Missing operator before images?)
String found where operator expected at test_8.pl line 23, at end of line
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at test_8.pl line 23, near "$ "images"
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at test_8.pl line 23.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl>
```

Comment: The error messages indicate you have or had the strings `$images`, `$/images`, or `$ images` (`$ "images`?) in your source code. Show us your actual code.

Comment: i have posted an update - where i posted the actual code - see above at the very beginning of the initial-posting... I look forward to hear from you. Note- you are rigth! I have done some mess at the line where i specify the place where the scritp should store the results. I guess that i made some mistakes here...can yiou help me and correct the line - so  that the script stores the results in the folder called "images" which  resides in exactly the same folder , as the script itself resides... thanks in advance - god bless  you

Comment: `open my $out, ">", $ "images" or die $!;` is incorrect, just as your error message says. That either $ should not be there or should have a var name with it.

Comment: thx alot i ll try it out: BTW - well how should i name this... how to accomplish...!?: - **like so:** 'images' love to hear from you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original post included the code

```
open(my $out, '>', "path/$name")
```

which is very much on the right track. To write a file whose name is contained in `$name` in the directory `images`, the correct syntax is

```
open(my $out, '>', "images/$name")
```

I'm not sure how you got off track and tried `$images`, `$/images`, and `$ images`.

Comment: hello dear mob - this line: open(my $out, '>', "images/$pics");
leads to the error - requires explicit package name at line 24... well should i write a package or file name at  the $name - or leave it as is?

Comment: i posted the full code that   does notwork in the  inital posting see above - there seems to  be some things with the code - avoiding perl to get to work - it does not run  and complains a explicit package-name at line 24 -.. love to hear from you

Comment: What is `$pics`? What happened to `$name`?

Comment: Hello dear socekt-puppet; thx for answering: i have created a folder called "images" - This following code does not run: open(my $out, '>', "images/$name")
Well  - to  be  frank: i am not sure how to treat "images/$name" and what i should do with $name. I thougth  that i had to choose a 
a explicit package name at line 24 - since the warnings complained this. Well - all i want  to do is to get the files stored in a folder. Note - i thougth i could name this  folder "images" - what  schould i do with $name!? Just look forward to your answer... greetings & thx in advance zero

Comment: mob you answer: To write a file whose name is contained in $name in the directory images,  Note - i do not want to write one file - there are as many files as i have urls to get screenshots from... so think it is pretty useless to say the script that i have to write only one file  - or did i get you wrong here. love to hear from you

Comment: @zero: `$name` has a different value in every iteration of your `while` loop, so what is the problem?

Comment: well ah yes i understand that means i can go exactly your "way". but why i get the problems in the commandline. note: i have a folder within the foder where the mechanize-script residses. this folder is called images. so i do not know why i get errors at all - well - do you know. in other words. does the script run at your site - does it run well?? love to hear from you

Comment: getting errors all the way long: martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
syntax error at test_8.pl line 25, near ")
 binmode"
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 25.
Global symbol "$out" requires explicit package name at test_8.pl line 26.
Execution of test_8.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> su -